# Finding the limit that involves Fourier coefficients,

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given the function $f(x) = 1 - \dfrac{|x|}{\pi}$, I had computed its Fourier coefficients, using integration by parts and got:

$$
a_n = \begin{cases} 0, & \text{for $n$ even}, \\[6pt]
\dfrac{2}{n^2\pi^2}, & \text{for $n$ odd}, \\[6pt]
\dfrac{1}{2}, & \text{for }n = 0.
\end{cases}
$$

So, I know the coefficients decay like $\dfrac{1}{n^2}$.

What if I now took $f(x)$ to be $\left(1 - \dfrac{|x|}{\pi}\right)^4$.

What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}$ $n^3a_n$?

This is part 2 of a question that I am working on, and the question does not ask for a detailed proof but rather just the answer and the reasoning behind it.

Thanks,

Edit:  Of course, if we iterate the integration by parts enough times, we can certainly compute the Fourier coefficients for the new function.  But this is quite a bit of computation and I'm sure is not the point of the question - part 1 of the question already asked for explicit computation of the $a_n$'s.  I'm not sure how to proceed, without direct computation.  Perhaps there are decay / growth conditions of the $a_n$'s and convergence properties of the Fourier series that I am not aware of...

Comment: Have you tried computing the coefficients for $f(x)=(1-\frac{|x|}{\pi})^2$? Or maybe you can share, the computation of the coefficients of your original function, to see if there is a pattern that you are omiting.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has Fourier series $\sum a_n \cos nt+b_n\sin nt$, then $f'$ has Fourier series $ \sum na_n \cos nt-na_n\sin nt$. (I treat these as formal series, making no claims about their convergence). So, whenever you see Fourier coefficients multiplied by powers of $n$, think of derivatives.

So the natural idea is to consider $f'''$, but the differentiability of $f$ isn't that great... which brings to mind the second idea.

Suppose $n^3 a_n$ is bounded. Then the series for $f'$ has coefficients bounded by $C/n^2$. (In your case, all $b_n$ vanish since the function is even.) It follows $f'$ is represented by a uniformly convergent Fourier series, and is therefore continuous.

However, for $f(x)=(1-|x|/\pi)^4$, the derivative $f'$ is not continuous at $0$. Hence, $\lim n^3 a_n$ does not exist.

Comment: Hi, @Idisagree, I would like to ask you one more question that's been lingering in my head since we last discussed your answer.  
Does the Weierstrass M-test, giving us uniform convergence to a continuous function, f', from the bound of C/n^2 of the coefficients, necessarily mean that the Fourier series for f' converges to f' for its *entire* domain of definition, which would be the (extended) real line?

Comment: I feel like you, and the M-test, must mean that, in order for your contradiction proof to work - you looked at x=0, which proves n^3*an must be unbounded.  you also didn't mention anything about the radius of convergence, which also makes me think that the *uniform* convergence to f' must be for its entire domain of definition and not restricted to a smaller interval.  Thanks,

Comment: There is no such thing as a radius of convergence of a Fourier series.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thanks a lot, @Idisagree!