# What is $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^3 a_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, alternative-proof

$a_n$ is the Fourier coefficient of $$f(x) = \left(1 - \frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)^4$$

The answer is infinity, but can someone give an answer that doesn't require explicit computation of the $a_n$?  I'm looking for an explanation that applies convergence and divergence results, and maybe even growth and decay conditions of the coefficients, of the Fourier series.

Thanks,

Edit:  Two things to note -

1) $a_n$ for $f(x) = \left(1 - \frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)$ decays like $\frac{1}{n^2}$.  Can I use this to say something about the decay of $a_n$ for $f(x) = \left(1 - \frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)^4$?

2) $f(x) = \left(1 - \frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)^4$ is not differentiable at zero.

Comment: Duplicate of [Finding the limit that involves Fourier coefficients,](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1329705#1332096)

Comment: Ah, ok, I just read your solution - very nice explanation, @ 3дравый Смысл.  But how does the bound of c/n^2 on the coefficients give the Fourier series, for f^1, uniform convergence?  I am guessing it's something similar to an application of the Weierstrass M-test, but this test uses a series of constants to bound the summands of the smaller series (smaller in absolute value.).  Also, f^1 is not differentiable (of course) at z = 0.  Does the Fourier series for f^1 *diverge* at z = 0?  Thanks,

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the M-test. Absolute convergence of Fourier coefficients  implies uniform convergence of the Fourier series.

Comment: No, the Fourier series of $f'$ does not diverge at $x=0$.  At that point, the function has a jump discontinuity: hence, the series converges to the average of the left and right limits. But this isn't essential here. The point is that $f'$, having a jump discontinuity, cannot have uniformly convergent Fourier series, and therefore the series of its coefficients is not **absolutely** convergent.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thank you very much for your help, @3дравый Смысл.

Comment: Actually, can I ask you one more question, @3дравый Смысл?  In your solution, you are considering the "generalized" Fourier series of f(x).  I have been looking at the complex Fourier series, and computing the coefficients for f^1 for a complex Fourier series (since that is what the question asked for.)  Are the generalized series and the complex series...equivalent?  I can't seem to justify this on paper -- the coefficients in the complex series are integrals being scaled by a factor of 1/2pi, while the coefficients of the generalized series are scaled by 1/pi.

Comment: You should post that as a separate question, but the short answer is yes: they are equivalent. The reason for different scaling is that when we use orthogonality to derive formulas for these coefficients, the integral of function squared comes up. And $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |e^{i kx}|^2 = 2\pi $ while $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos^2 kx = \pi$.

Comment: Ok, thank you, @3дравыйСмысл!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The function:
$$ f(x) = \left(1-\frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)^4 $$
vanishes in the endpoints of $[-\pi,\pi]$ together with its (weak) derivatives up to order $3$, hence the Fourier coefficient
$$ c_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)\, e^{-nix}\,dx $$
may be easily computed through integration by parts. That gives in advance that the rate of decay of the Fourier coefficients of $f(x)$ is the same as the rate of decay of the Fourier coefficients of $\left(1-\frac{|x|}{\pi}\right)$. For non-believers, $c_n$ defined as above is:
$$ c_n = \frac{8(n^2\pi^2-6)}{\pi^3 n^4}=\Theta\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).$$

Comment: Hi, @Jack D'Aurizio, are you iterating the integration by parts until the power reduces from 4 to 1?  Or, are you integrating only once?  I am looking at an exact computation of the $a_n$ for f^4, and it doesn't look pleasant nor nightmare-ish; the question just asks for an explanation and reasoning of why the coefficients for f^4 must be unbounded.  but if you indeed integrated without some sort of iteration process, can you please elaborate a little bit more on your final equation in your solution?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames: integrate by parts till the power drops from $4$ to $1$. I have computed yet $c_n$ in closed form, and I bet you are able to integrate by parts too without any further expansion of my answer. Moreover, this question has been marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks for your help, @JackD'Aurizio!